# What is the best way (in Rails/AR) to ensure writes to a database table are performed synchronously, one after another, one at a time?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, delayed-job

I have noticed that using something like delayed_job without a UNIQUE constraint on a table column would still create double entries in the DB. I have assumed delayed_job would run jobs one after another. The Rails app runs on Apache with Passenger Phusion. I am not sure if that is the reason why this would happen, but I would like to make sure that every item in the queue is persisted to AR/DB one after another, in sequence, and to never have more than one write to this DB table happen at the same time. Is this possible? What would be some of the issues that I would have to deal with?

#### update

The race conditions arise because an AJAX API is used to send data to the application. The application received a bunch of data, each batch of data is identified as belonging together by a Session ID (SID), in the end, the final state of the database has to include the latest most up-to date AJAX PUT query to the API. Sometimes queries arrive at the exact same time for the same SID -- so I need a way to make sure they don't all try to be persisted at the same time, but one after the other, or simply the last to be sent by AJAX request to the API.

I hope that makes my particular use-case easier to understand...

Comment: Why down-vote? Don't hate, explain. Be constructive. to StackOverflow staff, down-votes should not be possible without an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for whoever negated the down-vote.

Comment: fwiw, you can create database inconsistency issues (leaving things like delayed job out of the mix) simply by having multiple processes read/update the database without proper consideration for concurrency...  some detail about the specific table and how it is being used would help here, I think...

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code from the job, but perhaps you're creating some AR objects, then the job fails, but the objects stay and are then recreated by a parallel job. You may need to use DB transactions so you can roll back in case of an intermediate failure.

Comment: I have updated a the description with a bit more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock a specific table (or tables) with the `LOCK TABLES` statement.

In general I would say that relying on this is poor design and will likely lead to with scalability problems down the road since you're creating an bottleneck in your application flow.

With your further explanations, I'd be tempted to add some extra columns to the table used by delayed_job, with a unique index on them. If (for example) you only ever wanted 1 job per user you'd add a `user_id` column  and then do

```
something.delay(:user_id => user_id).some_method
```

You might need more attributes if the pattern is more sophisticated, e.g. there are lots of different types of jobs and you only wanted one per person, per type, but the principle is the same. You'd also want to be sure to rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and deal with it gracefully.

For non delayed_job stuff, optimistic locking is often a good compromise between handling the concurrent cases well without slowing down the non concurrent cases.

Comment: Yes, I understand this... I'm not sure how else to make sure a batch of queries gets persisted in sequential order though. Unless I time-stamp each entry and write them all separately and run some sort of a batch job in the background to merge the ones with the same ID...

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried/troubled about/with multiple processes writing to the 'same' rows - as in more users updating the same order_header row - I'd suggest you set some marker bound to the current_user.id on the row once /order_headers/:id/edit was called, and removing it again, once the current_user releases the row either by updating or canceling the edit.

Your use-case (from your description) seems a bit different to me, so I'd suggest you leave it to the DB (in case of a fairly recent - as in post 5.1 - MySQL, you'd add a trigger/function which would do the actual update, and here - you could implement similar logic to the above suggested; some marker bound to the sequenced job id of sorts)